# Highlighting keywords in string, allowing "at", "in", "on"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For each Article there is a list of keywords which are currently highlighted (wrapped in span with class). However, I need to allow for certain prepositions within the keyword ("at", "in", "on"). Each article belongs to an Order which contains the keywords as a comma separated string.

For example, if I have a long tail keyword like "boutique hotels london" and the article contains the words "boutique hotels **in** london" I need to highlight that as a keyword.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def format_content
    words = self.content

    # map comma separated keywords into array and remove any whitespace
    keywords = self.order.keywords.downcase.split(',').map{ |k| k.strip }

    # replace words with keywords wrapped in span
    keywords.each do |word|
      words = words.gsub(/(#{word})/i, "<span class=\"text-primary\">\\1</span>")
    end

    words
  end
end
```

The format_content method is used in a partial from the show view after an article is created, like so:

```
<%= simple_format article.format_content, { class: "content" }, wrapper_tag: "p" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough to just create a list of keywords with prepositions concatenated?

```
keywords_with_prepositions = prepositions.flat_map do |preposition|
  keywords.map do |keyword|
    [keyword, "#{keyword} #{preposition}", "#{preposition} #{keyword}", "something other in combinatation with your #{keyword}"]
  end
end
```

My suggestion is to move this out of the model and into a decorator or helper. Also the `require` in the method should be moved some levels up.

Comment: This would catch pre / post words but not those in between the long tail keywords. Needs to work for "boutique hotel *in* London" while the keyword is "boutique hotel London"

Comment: so it should only work for prepositions in between keywords?

Comment: Yes for those in between keywords (a 'keyword' can be several words long in this case) but also for direct matches when no preposition is required.

Comment: So just create the combinations as required?
If you don't know how, then add some desired inputs and outputs to the question.